# TextView is not fit in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview

I have a problem that TextView doesn't match with ScrollView ...

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewSlide"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/txtPassage"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

s.th that shows and is false (better to say in this way that about 5 first line is hidden)[image]

Comment: unclear what are you asking...

Comment: It is kind of hard to explain, i mean scrollview cut textview , for example textview has 10 lines but it shows 7 lines !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/li1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Hellofgbjfdkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkhbhbghbuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuubfiiiiiiiiiibigyygfjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj\nfjgggggggggggggggg\ngfggggggggggggggggggg\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\njgjijhijghijgfhjgfhjigfjhijgfhjgi
            jfdjgkfjd\nkkgkfgklfkgfg"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code this will help

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/li1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```